# /bin/bash (chrooted) no longer works

Tags: linux, sshd, chroot, plesk, chroot-jail

Previously all our web customers were setup to access their SFTP using the shell /bin/bash(chrooted). As of 1-17-17 it was working for everyone. The following monday 1-20-17 it was not. This issue is affecting ALL domains that used /bin/bash(chrooted) as the shell.

When trying to connect, FTP error: EOF while reading packet. Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance.

When trying to connect via SSH on command line, error: Could not chdir to home directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com: No such file or directory /usr/local/psa/bin/chrootsh: No such file or directory Connection to domain.com closed.

I can't find any record of any relevant updates to Plesk, I certainly didn't change anything. The only update I see in Plesk history is an update from PHP 7 to PHP 7.0.14. I've been doing some searching, what I found(in below examples, I replaced the actual username with "username" and the actual domain with "domain.com"):

1. The FTP user in /etc/passwd shows correctly as far as I can tell: username:x:10057:1004::/var/www/vhosts/domain.com:/usr/local/psa/bin/chrootsh
2. there have been no changes to user or group permissions. The user is correctly assigned to the psacln group, just like before.
3. The /var/www/vhosts/chroot folder has everything it needs as far as I can tell, and all permissions and ownership are correct.
4. I have tried the method from Plesk here: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909545--HOWTO-How-to-add-new-programs-to-a-chrooted-shell-environment-template, didn't work. I even renamed the chroot folder to chroot_old and reinstalled, no difference.
5. I have tried adding user-specific rules to the sshd_config file in /etc: Match User username ChrootDirectory /var/www/vhosts/chroot Then restarting sshd, no go.
6. I also ran the plesk repair utility from this link: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/a...epair-utility/plesk-repair-utility-web.74654/ and it found nothing related to my issue.

I have no idea what else to check, and changing the shell to /bin/bash is not an option - besides the security risk we have customers with automated SSH connections that require the chroot for their file/folder pathways. My server support is stumped.

I would appreciate anyone's help!! Thank you.

Comment: What is output of `ls -la /usr/local/psa/bin/chrootsh` ? What is you OS name and version?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  The result is:

`-rwsr-x--- 1 root psacln 10536 Oct 28 00:52 /usr/local/psa/bin/chrootsh`

Cent OS 7, Plesk 17.0.17

Comment: Have you tried to switch shell to common bash and back to chrooted bash? If it doesn't help I think you can contact Plesk support directly, as i know it's free now.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Previously, "cycling" the shell would fix the problem, but it didn't this time.  I have tried getting Plesk support but they require a plesk license in their support form, and when I did that I get a message that they don't support plesk installations by a third party (in this case, my host Mediatemple) and that I need to contact them (which I have, multiple times - they're stumped).  In the end, I had a linux guy I know completely reinstall it - I will add an answer to this question to reflect that.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem, essentially chroot was reinstalled.  I had another guy who knows way more than me do it, but I did ask him to try to summarize what he did so it might help anyone else who has to do the same thing:

1. Essentially, he took the executables that existed in the original CHROOT source directory & copied them to the CHROOT source directory I created when I ran the script from the Plesk docs above: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909545--HOWTO-How-to-add-new-programs-to-a-chrooted-shell-environment-template.
2. Then, he cleaned up any remnants of the original CHROOT environment in each account (e.g. removed the bin, sbin, etc and so on directories under the hosting account (/var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com)
3. Then, set shell to anything but the chroot option (in plesk -> subscription -> web hosting access & save. Then, set the shell to chroot option (/bin/bash(chrooted).  This last item triggers commands to remove & add the chroot environment to the targeted directory.

I'm still in the process of doing step 2 and 3 for my remaining domains, but so far it has worked everytime. Hopefully that will help someone that has a similar issue.

Comment: +1 for sharing your solution. Have you discovered what the cause was?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Neither our server support, the guy that reinstalled chroot, nor myself ever found the actual cause of the issue. If I had to make a somewhat educated guess, I think an update might have accidentally removed a dependency with chroot.  Since it was server wide and affected all domains, I have to think that it was something having to do with the chroot folder in /var/www/vhosts/chroot/, possibly a corrupted file?  Then when I switched to /bin/bash/ and back to /bin/bash(chrooted), Plesk wasn't properly removing and restoring the relevant files and dependencies.